# Farkas' lemma with matrix as variables.

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization

I have this problem: provided a matrix $A$ and vectors $n$ and $b$, i want to know whether the following system is feasible:

$$X^Tn>b$$
$$AX\leq0$$

(here, the second lines means that the matrix $AX$ has all its entries being negative, not that it is definite negative).

I thought of using farkas lemma to generate the equivalent system and check it that's unfeasible, but I'm having problems generating it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

$\textbf{What I've tried:}$ looking column by column in the matrix $X$, the problem is equivalent to the following system being true for all $i$:

$$n^Tx_i>b_i$$
$$Ax_i\leq0$$

from there, i tried using the variant shown in page 6 of [http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236a/lectures/alternatives.pdf](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/ee236a/lectures/alternatives.pdf), but got a condition that is always true, so i know its not the way to go. I haven't been able to find a version of farkas lemma that works with those kind of inequalities.

Thanks in advance!